# Missunderstanding with task, async, await, example with SendRequestAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

If I call this method (1.) nothing happens and I don't know why. 
If I just call model.TestConnection(null); without Result I hit Breakpoint 1 but then I dont wait for the result.

**So, why didn' I hit any Breakpoint when I call model.TestConnection(null).Result?
And why do I hit them when I just call model.TestConnection(null);?**

The method GetUrl calls SendRequestAsync and awaits it result, then it returns its content.
This all happens as a task, so you can await GetUrl to get the content. But there seems to be a big missunderstanding on my side regarding the Task Parallel Library (TPL).

1. ```
   var result = model.TestConnection(null).Result;
   ```
2. ```
   public class CcuMockModel : CcuModelBase, ICcuModel
   {
       public Task<CheckLoginResult> TestConnection(string url)
       {
          return GetUrl(@"http://localhost:8080/api/getObjects");
       }
   }
   ```
3. ```
   public class CcuModelBase
   {
       public async Task<CheckLoginResult> GetUrl(string url)
       {
           var aHBPF = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
           aHBPF.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
           aHBPF.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);

           var client = new HttpClient(aHBPF);

           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url));

           HttpResponseMessage response;
           try
           {
               response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
               // Breakpoint 1
               return new CheckLoginResult()
               {
                   Content = response.Content.ToString(),
                   Status = CheckLoginResult.ErrorCode.Ok
               };
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
           }
           // Breakpoint 2
           return new CheckLoginResult() {Status = CheckLoginResult.ErrorCode.Failed};
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It's possible you were downvoted for a poorly formatted question. What exactly is the question?

Comment: It looks like you have a deadlock. The continuation after `client.SendRequestAsync` cannot be run since the caller is blocking on the returned task `model.TestConnection(null).Result` if the current synchronisation context wants to run the continuation on the same thread. See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx Lee for the Link http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
This exlains a lot and helped me with my understanding for task, async and await.

I blocked my task with

```
var result = model.TestConnection(null).Result;
```

Now I await and everything works properly.

```
private async static void Testing()
{
    var result = await model.TestConnection(null);
}
```